# Codeigniter - Shows a blank page after successful login

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having this weird problem in the redirection after a successful login.
Whenever I go to my site, I am presented with a login form. After I put in the valid details and submit them, I get redirected to a blank page.
But...If I click on the address bar and press enter, it redirects/shows me to the wanted page.
Anyone knows what's the problem?

Redirection code:

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
     if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])){
        $this->load->view('vwSignin');
          redirect('Signin');
     else {
            <loads the login form again>
     }
     }
```

Comment: Is PHP error reporting turned on? It's likely that your server is having an internal 500 error and you don't know it. Also, in the Network tab of your dev tools you should check the response from your server. In Google Chrome, press F12 and go to the Network tab, then try logging in and monitor the very first entry in the list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yeah, PHP error reporting is turned on since I get a few errors after I redirect myself to the wanted page (errors that I am planning on fixing later). I already tried monitoring the process of the redirection by console and by the network tab. By console I get nothing - blank. By the network tab I get an OK message.

Comment: I get no response from the server from some reason. It just transfers the login credentials forward and that's it.

Comment: So, nothing interesting in these tabs? http://i.stack.imgur.com/ov6KR.png

Comment: Did you check your error logs?

Comment: Can you post your redirect code?

Comment: Nope, nothing interesting there. error logs are empty (they are always empty).

Comment: if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
  if(isset($this->session->userdata['logged_in'])){
    $this->load->view('vwSignin');
    redirect('Signin');

Comment: The "redirect('Signin')" is just something I stupidly tried accomplishing.

Comment: Update your question and add the relevant code; it will make it much easier to read.

Comment: I updated the question with the relevant code.

Comment: Your action should be wether loading view wether redirect. You don't need `redirect()` function when login failed - just loading form view. When login passed you can use one of those.

Comment: I've cleaned up and aligned your code for you. Do you see the error now?